# Solr getting started in docker

Tags: solr, docker

I downloaded solr-5.2.1.tgz and extracted it in /aDirectory.

Started a docker container having java:

```
root@0cde4d5716e6:/solr/solr-5.2.1# java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Tried the [quickstart](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) and got stuck at the first solar command given:

```
root@0cde4d5716e6:/solr/solr-5.2.1# bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt

Welcome to the SolrCloud example!


Starting up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.

Starting up SolrCloud node1 on port 8983 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983  -m 512m 



Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=325). Happy searching!
```

I am clearly missing the server on port 7574. The link: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cloud?view=tree shows me only the node on port 8983.

Started docker with the following command:

```
    docker run -it --rm \
     -v ~/tmp/solr:/solr \
     -w /solr \
     -p 8983:8983 \
     -p 7574:7574 \
     --name solr \
     solr:dev \
     bash
```

The picture I am supposed to see in my cloud tab is obviously not showing either.

Works on the host if I don't use a docker container. Is there any way to find out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, docker image is ubuntu:14:04 with java installed but missing lsof and curl.

Just had a look in the solr bash script and see that it needs that but silently fails.